# No sdb partion when trying to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

I'm trying to create a dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 on my Inspiron-15-3000 series following [this tutoriel in French made by Playmatic24](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTIIx9-ZAyw&index=1&list=LLTwrHQWU2uh5jj5jH3PXTFw)

I didn't achied it when notifying many differences :

- I don' have a partition `sdb` along an `sda`
- I think I disactivated the UEFI when uploading Ubuntu 14.4 for the fist time one year ago and some messaged pop-uped to warn me about something about it. May I follow up installation if I clicked on "not to force the uefi mode installation" ?

Here is a screenshot of the option where I stopped before choosing the "other option" installing option. 
[image]
 - I had a weird "ubuntu" option for booting in the grey and blue screen. Maybe it is normal because of my first Ubuntu 14.4 or 16.4 installations ...

My question is : may I have continued by partitioning with the three mounting option (for `/`, `/home` and the lastion I don't remember the name...) or do I miss something?

I tried then [this tutorial in English from everydaylinuxuser.com](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html), changing my fast boot option and secure boot option to down and now I'm not able to boot on Windows anymore, even from the blue and grey screen.

#### Update 2/5/2017

Here is the boot info :

http://txt.do/drvsx

Comment: The link to the boot-info summary is not correct, nothing to see there.

Comment: @mook765 It is the only thing I get from boot-info

Comment: @mook765 I don't know what the issue is when creating an url but here is the boot-info created as a local text

Comment: Yes , this is more helpful. It appears that just right now only Windows is installed,  and Windows is installed in legacy-mode. You should install Ubuntu in legacy-mode too, if you install Ubuntu in UEFI-mode, you will run into problems. To install Ubuntu in legacy-mode, you have to boot the installer in legacy-mode. In the BIOS boot menu you will see two items for your installer, one of them starts with `UEFI:`. You have to choose the other one.

Comment: @mook765 Understood. Is it normal that I'm not able to boot on windows now from the blue and grey screen ?

Comment: I think your Windows is  damaged, boot repair says that it would check the file systems and perform fix-windows-boot. If you want to repair anything with boot-repair, you have to boot in legacy-mode as your OS's are installed in legacy-mode. probably you will need a Windows-recovery-DVD. Always it is important to boot in the correct boot-mode, which is legacy-mode in your case.

Comment: @mook765 I followed your advise and installed in legacy mode. It works ! Thanks for the help ! I don't even know what is the difference between UEFI and legacy ;)

Comment: That is what we are here for, to help. Glad it is solved. If you want to know more about this topic, dive into the links provided by @Rod Smith. Consider to upvote his answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't speak French, so I can't follow a French YouTube video. That said, I have some comments on your query:

- `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are entirely separate physical hard disks, not partitions. If your guide showed both but you have just one, it means that you have fewer hard disks than whoever wrote the guide. (The installation medium itself might show up as `/dev/sdb`, though, which can complicate the comparison.) Partitions are *numbered* and referred to with numbers following the disk device filename, as in `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sdb4`.
- As a general rule, if you want to dual-boot Ubuntu with an existing OS, you should ***NOT*** adjust EFI/UEFI vs. BIOS/CSM/legacy boot options. See [my page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for a detailed presentation on why this is so.
- It's hard to tell from your description how your computer is set up. To provide detailed information, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.

I recommend you read the following pages:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[A question and answers on the differences between BIOS and EFI booting on Superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)** -- This provides the basics of the preceding, but is more concise.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog.
- **[My page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)** -- This page covers the CSM, including when it's useful and when it's not.
- **[The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)** -- This page is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.
- **[This site's question on installing on EFI-based systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)** -- This is yet another EFI-mode installation guide.

---

**EDIT:** Your existing Windows installation is definitely in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. As such, you should *not* attempt to install Ubuntu in EFI/UEFI mode. To avoid doing so, you *must* learn to control the boot mode of your computer. This involves both properly creating your boot media and somehow selecting the boot mode used to boot an individual medium. Typically, you'll see two options for a USB drive, one with the string "UEFI" and one without it. Selecting the one without "UEFI" is the appropriate choice. Read my page on the CSM (referenced above) for more information; *however,* that page is written mainly for people who have EFI-mode Windows installations and who might be tempted (through frustration or bad instructions) to install Linux in BIOS mode. You have the opposite problem.

Comment: This is too much complicated for me.  I just wanted to know wether to click or not on force the uefi mode installation. I followed another tutorial turning off secure boot and fast boot and now my pc isn't even booting on Windows anymore

Comment: Neither Secure Boot nor Fast Boot options should affect Windows' ability to boot, so I suspect you did something else to affect it -- either a firmware setting or an accidental change to on-disk files. It's impossible to offer you more advice without *detailed* information on your current configuration, such as from the Boot Repair utility to which I referred in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I just ran the boot-repair in the terminal and added the url which is quite odd as far as I only have http://paste2.org/ . I did it from the `try ubuntu ` OS

Comment: Please see my edit, above.